# Testing push notifications on iPhone (APNS)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

I have uploaded my SSL certificates to my project, focusing on the aps_development.cer.

When I launch my app, I get prompted asking if I want to allow notifications, so that is working properly. It's that the actual notification is not passing through.

My server appears that it is able to send a notification, and I am sending it to my device token.

I'm assuming it might be something with my code signing in Xcode. Is there something different I should be doing?

[image]

Comment: Is your server connecting to the `sandbox` or `production` server?

Comment: @chedabob It is connecting here: `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, so sandbox.

Comment: Try sending a push with this: https://github.com/nomad/houston If that doesn't work, it narrows it down to an issue with your app

Answer (score -1):

Preparing your app for push notifications is a long task. With the information your are giving it is not clear that what you are doing wrong.

When I look at it at first I see that no provisioning profile selected. You can't send push notifications without selecting appropriate provisioning profile.

Also what about your pem files and other stuff like gateway url etc?

You can follow these [instructions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to make push notifications work.